# SYMFONY FORM ChoiceType, multiple=>true. How to by pass the need to implement Data Transformers

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

In a SYMFONY FORM (ORM is not use (PDO is used for DB query instead)).

I have a class MyEntityType in which the buildForm function has:

```
$builder->add('my_attribute',ChoiceType::class,array(
  'choices'=>$listForMyAttribute,
  'multiple'=>'true',
  'attr'=>array('data-native-menu'=>'false'),
  'label'=>'Multiple Select on my attribute'
));
```

My attribute is an array of an entity named MyEntity which has:

```
/**
* @Assert\NotBlank()
*/
private $myAttribute;
```

With a getter and a setter for that variable $myAttribute.

When I submit the form in the Controller, it doesn't pass the validation check and logs this error:

**Unable to reverse value for property path "myAttribute" : Could not find all matching choices for the given values.**

When I start to look  for solution around this error message, it leads to something named "How to Use Data Transformers" in SYMFONY Cookbook; And it seems a solution would involve to create new Class and write a lot of code for something that one should be able to by-pass in a much straight forward way.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hi @nyluje, could you give the value of `$listForMyAttribute` please?

Comment: What type is `$myAttribute`?

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin it seems that my $listForMyAttribute is an empty array, I get 1 when I do is_array($listForMyAttribute) in some log before, $builder->add('my_attribute'...)), also it is weird because the display on the screen of the multiple choice contains really the list that I want (the list is a SQL that retrieves an array to display in the option tags of a select), so I don't understand why the log would give and empty array. (I'll delete Le monde de M. Fred comments if you don't mind)

Comment: @dragoste, $myAttribute is an array. No type defined for the array.

Comment: @nyluje If some $listForMyAttribute is an empty array when adding it to the form build, I don't see why some choices would be displayed... Could you dump its value and send it?

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin , actually, having a closer look on what is happening, it is not an empty array when the form get displayed (before I do the submit), so I can see all my options in the select, it is once I click on the submit, during that process it goes thru again the buildForm and there the array is empty (because I apply some condition to create that array that are likely not respected after the submit event)

Comment: Hum, that seems to be hard to reproduce your exact case then. You need to have the choices array provided for the form even when it's submitted, you will get validation issues otherwise. That's a requirement, but probably not sufficient enough for your example to work.

Comment: I investigate further on that direction to understand my mistake. your comment helped to drive me in that direction thanks'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my array $listForMyAttribute was defined in the buildForm() function and its definition was relying on some conditional.

**The conditional to make the array were met when this one was displayed for the first time.**

**After pushing the submit button**, the buildForm was regenerated in the Controller, **this second time, the condition were not met to make the array $listForMyAttribute** as it was on the first display. Hence the program was **throwing a "contraint not met error" because the value submited for that field could not be find**.

Answer (score 0):

Today I face exactly the same problem. Solution is simple as 1-2-3.

1) Create utility dummy class `DoNotTransformChoices`

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface;

class DoNotTransformChoices implements ChoiceListInterface 
{
    public function getChoices() { return []; }
    public function getValues() { return []; }
    public function getPreferredViews() { return []; }
    public function getRemainingViews() { return []; }
    public function getChoicesForValues(array $values) { return $values; }
    public function getValuesForChoices(array $choices) { return $choices; }
    public function getIndicesForChoices(array $choices) { return $choices; }
    public function getIndicesForValues(array $values) { return $values; }
}
```

2) Add to your field the following additional option:

```
   ...
   'choice_list' => new DoNotTransformChoices,
   ...
```

3) Congratulations!